# Implementing jQuery "closest"

Tags: jquery

I am using this jQuery function to find the parent element with class name "viewCommentsExp".

```
 $('.viewCommentsExpBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

var trackid= $(this).parent().find(".trackidField2").val();
var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".viewCommentsExp");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "trackid="+trackid,
            url: "http://rt.ja.com/viewcomments.php",
            success: function(data)
            {   
             $(".newUserComment").html(data);
            $(parent).slideToggle();

                }
            });
     });
```

I have this function working on about 90% of the clicks.  But, randomly, sometimes all divs with this classname are selected rather than the closest.

Can I clean this up to work more reliably using jQuery "closest"?

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".viewCommentsExp");
```

Not sure how to implement this.

Comment: What's the structure of your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the elements being clicked will have a parent with some characteristic you can use (e.g., a class name or other attribute), then `closest` might be helpful. It depends on your HTML structure, which you haven't shown (as of this writing, I'm guessing you'll probably add it, but I have to disappear).

For instance, if the elements will be in something with the class "container", and the "viewCommentsExp" is a descendant of that "container" element, then:

```
var viewCommentsExp = $(this).closest(".container").find(".viewCommentsExp");
```

That would work, for instance, if you were looking for clicks on the button in this structure:

```
<div class="container">
<input type="button">
<span class="viewCommentsExp">...</span>
</div>
```

...or any other structure where both the button and the "viewCommentsExp" were descendants of "container" (whether siblings or not).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the jQuery function `closest()`.

```
var parent = $(this).closest('.viewCommentsExp');
```

Since the function `closest` returns a jQuery object, no need to wrap it again.

`parent.slideToggle();`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

var parent = $(this).closest('.viewCommentsExp');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why are you adding an answer 11 years later that adds nothing new compared to the existing answers?